# Null Pointer Exception error in android- fatal build error

Tags: android

Hi I got a null pointer error on this line

> layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.instructions1, null);

I have checked everything. The instructions 1 is an XML file and it exists in the layout folder within the `Resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try relaunch Eclipse if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

instructions1.xml is in your res/layout/ and inflater is not null ? please check again~

clean your project and have a try~

Comment: Yes the inflater is not null

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the inflater as a final? Maybe you're triggering the NPE when you dereference it.

Beyond that it's hard to say without any code or logcats to troubleshoot.